# How do I show that commuting matrices preserve generalized eigenspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let T and S be two linear operators on V, such that TS = ST. How do I show that T preserves the generalized eigenspaces of S?

There were 2 similar questions, but they were a lot more advanced than my current level, so they didn't help.

Comment: Hint: If $x$ is an eigenvector of $TS$, then $Sx$ is an eigenvector of $ST$.

Comment: Is $V$ finite dimensional or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $TS = ST \implies T(S - \lambda I) = (S- \lambda I)T$ and $T(S -\lambda I)^{k} = (S - \lambda I)^{k}T$.

Comment: Right. Wasn't sure if it was safe to say that $TS=ST⟹T(S−λI)=(S−λI)T$. Is there a proof for that, or is it something that should be assumed?

Comment: Could you not just write it out? $T(S- \lambda I) = TS - \lambda T$ and $(S- \lambda I)T = ST - \lambda T$. Now I am saying $a - c = b - c$ whenever $a = b$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda$ be eigenvalue of $S$ and $Sv=\lambda v$. Since $TS=ST$
$$
T(Sv)=S(Tv)=S(\lambda v)=\lambda Sv
$$
This means that $Sv$ is also eigenvector of $T$, i.e. eigenspace of $T$, $E_{\lambda}(T)$ is invariant under $S$.

Comment: This only implies that the eigenspaces, not necessarily *generalized eigenspaces*, are preserved.

Comment: It is enough to show it for any eigenvector of $S$